# Underscore _.map function results in a paragraph

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am calling an underscore _.map having a function, but I want the results in a paragraph. How can I achieve it?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<p> </P>
<script>
_.map([1,2,3],function(e){return e*3;});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The results must print inside my paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><script>
            _.map([1,2,3],function(e){document.write(e*3);});
        </script></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Update to accommodate comment request**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="target"></p>
        <script>
            _.map([1,2,3],function(e){
                document.getElementById('target').innerHTML=(e*3);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Still cannot see the results? Can u have a fiddle ??